# Авторизация по OAuth2, как организовать выдачу access_token?

Tags: yii2, rest, oauth, oauth2

Нужно сделать авторизацию по OAuth2 для rest api на yii2.
Взял вот такое расширение: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-oauth2-server

Настроил доступ по access_token, который пока вручную забит в базу.
Для этого добавил в behaviors такое поведение:

```
'tokenAuth' => [
                'class' => \conquer\oauth2\TokenAuth::className(),
            ]
```

Это работает: с правильным токеном пускает, с неправильным не пускает, совсем без токена код 400.

Что не понятно... По OAuth2 токен, client_id и прочее выдаётся пользователю после того, как он успешно авторизовался на сервере авторизации и после этого он уже с токеном отправляется на сервер ресурсов, где этот токен проверяют.

В моём случае, сервер авторизации и сервер ресурсов - это одно и то же rest api.
Клиент должен залогиниться на нём отправив на /api/login post-запрос со своими логином/паролем, как он это делал всегда, и после этого ему должны выдать access_token.

А как он может залогиниться, если на /api/login как и на все методы API уже проверяется токен?

Собственно,  вопрос сводится к тому,  как подключить поведение не ко всем экшенам контроллера, а только к тем, где оно нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл отписаться, как была решена проблема.
Просто отнаследовался от TokenAuth и реализовал правила, как в поведении yii\filters\AccessControl.

```
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => [ 'signup' ] ,
                'allow' => true ,
                'roles' => [ '?' ] ,
            ] , [
                'actions' => [ 'logout' ] ,
                'allow' => true ,
                'roles' => [ '@' ] ,
            ] ,
        ] ,
```